# Should we use an interface as dependency (in ctor) even if what we expect is one specific implementation?

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

Let's say we have a class, for example `SqlIdProvider`, that needs an SQL repository to perform some operations. We also have an `SqlRepository` class that implements an `IRepository` interface like follows:

```
public interface IRepository {
    // All repository methods here.
}

public sealed class SqlRepository : IRepository {
    // All repository methods here.
}

public sealed class SqlIdProvider {
    private IRepository _repository;

    public SqlIdProvider(IRepository repository){
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

The `SqlIdProvider` has a strong dependency on `SqlRepository`, so it will not work if I provide, for example, an instance of the following class:

```
public sealed class MongoRepository : IRepository {
    // All repository methods here.
}
```

However, the signature of `SqlIdProvider` tells me that I could just provide one of these and everything should be fine.

In this situation, I usually think of three options:

1) Keep as is, and hope that the name will be enough for others to know that you shouldn't provide a `MongoRepository` to an `SqlIdProvider` (though not enforcing it in any way).

2) Change the `SqlIdProvider` constructor to take the concrete `SqlRepository`. This would enforce the requirement, but it would difficult unit testing, forcing us to remove the `sealed` keyword from `SqlRepository` to be able to fake the implementation (btw, I like classes to be sealed unless there's a good reason not to).

3) Create an *empty* interface that extends `IRepository`, designated for the sole purpose of SQL repositories, called `ISqlRepository`. Now, we could change the `SqlIdProvider` constructor to take the `ISqlRepository` interface instead.

```
public interface ISqlRepository : IRepository {
    // This one is empty on purpose.
}
```

To me, option 3) seems to be the most appealing, however still feels a like I'm doing something wrong here by creating an empty interface.

Is there any better way we can be explicit with the constraint and at the same time allow easy unit testing?

Comment: There is 4) which is: do not make this dependendy explicit but rather, make the sql repository private member of the `SqlIdProvider`, have the `SqlIdProvider` constructor parameterless and do not confuse anyone trying to fall into a possible trap you set there :)

Comment: @WiktorZychla but then how do I test `SqlIdProvider`? By the way, this is not a real case, just one I thought it would easily reflect the problem.

Comment: well, either it won´t matter because all providers **are** interchangable, or you have some specific behaviour for the providers, in which case you should also have different interfaces for them. So why do you care if this is an `SqlRepo` or a `MongoRepo`, if the entire functionality of both is described via the `IRepository`-interface?

Comment: @marcofo88: and how do you test the `SqlRepository`? Or a `SmtpEmailClient`? Point is, either it's a low level class that deals with infrastructure and you test it against a real infrastructure. Or it can be parametrized with a low level class of specific interface. This means that from your 1-3, 3 is my choice.

Comment: thanks @HimBromBeere! Indeed, if it was the first case you mention, using a generic version of `IdProvider` would suffice. In the case of having some specific behavior (the case I'm interested in), you mean to do something like in option 3) ?

Comment: I think what is creating the confusion here (at least for me) is that the `SqlIdProvider` class does not have an abstraction. An important question that needs to be answered is in my opinion "Who is going to utilize the SqlIdProvider and why?". If I am to instantiate the (both baseless and sealed) `SqlIdProvider`, that would be "coding to implementation". I also think that, if I need the `SqlIdProvider` I am already dealing with an `SqlRepository`. Therefore; would it not be better for providing an ID to be a feature of IRepository and only SQLRepository to implement it?

Comment: How would the `SqlIdProvider` class have any idea of what specific implementation it receives ? The `IRepository` interface defines what methods and return types are available to the calling class. By having a dependency on an interface, the whole idea is that you should be able to switch the concrete implementation without affecting the dependent class. If your `SqlIdProvider` class only is dependent on `IRepository` then technically speaking it should be able to function with either implementation considering the methods and return types should be the same.

Comment: @jandrew that's exactly my point. Let's assume `SqlIdProvider` has particular SQL logic that queries an table to get an ID. On the other hand, assume that if we also had a Mongo data source we wouldn't need an "IdProvider" at all. This is just to make emphasis on the fact that `SqlIdProvider` is really only for SQL.

Comment: Keep the Liskov substitution principle in mind. If your `SqlIdProvider` class can not take another implementation of `IRepository` without throwing exceptions, then you need to rethink the design. It's difficult to recommend a specific solution without knowing the details of your `SqlIdProvider` class, what public members it exposes and who is using it. If it needs methods specific to a `SqlRepository` then you need a separate interface for those additional methods that are on top of those defined by `IRepository`.

Comment: @jandrew that's a very good point! I would say that using something like option 3, even if it "works" it's still a sign that the design may be inadequate, unless the extended interface has something extra we would require here as you say.

Comment: I would probably go with option 3. Even though marker interfaces (empty interface designed for the soul purpose of marking whatever class that implements it as "something" is considered as an anti pattern - and with good reasons, I might add) - with your current design that seems like the lesser of all evils - unless, of course, you can still re-design your classes - and if that's the case, then all bets are off.